# Is there a way to make the MoveNext() part of foreach loop retry the operation when applied to result of Azure Storage Library ListBlobs()?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, exception, azure-storage

I have code using Azure Storage Library that goes like this:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = obtainContainer();

var blobList = container.ListBlobs(options:OptionsWithLinearRetry);
foreach (var blobItem in blobList) // << exception happens here sometimes
{
     //process item
}
```

and it works okay most of the time. But sometimes something goes wrong with the network and then I get:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

and the stack is like this:

```
// lots of Azure Storage Library stuff here
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.<>c__DisplayClass13.<ListBlobs>b__12(IContinuationToken token)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.General.<LazyEnumerable>d__0`1.MoveNext()
// my code with foreach line here
```

and so it looks like the foreach causes a `MoveNext()` call and the latter fails when obtaining the new chunk of data.

Can I somehow cause that `MoveNext()` call to be retried? Is there a way to have a "try-catch-retry" logic in foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

No matter how retry in next milliseconds, it will throw same exception, until it's totally closed. because your storage account is hitting the **thresholds/limit** which is specified by  Windows Azure Storage: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/11/04/cross-post-windows-azures-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets/

Actually not only Azure, also Google services and AWS are same, all of them have thresholds on remote calls.

The MSDN [cloudblobcontainer.listblobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet) says:

> Returns an **enumerable** collection of the blobs in the container that are retrieved **lazily**.

you can setup

1. [BlobRequestOptions.RetryPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.retrypolicy?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_RetryPolicy) in next 0-30 seconds.
2. [BlobRequestOptions.AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.absorbconditionalerrorsonretry?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_AbsorbConditionalErrorsOnRetry)
3. [BlobRequestOptions.MaximumExecutionTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.maximumexecutiontime?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_MaximumExecutionTime)

You detect retry by the events:

1. [OperationContext.GlobalRetrying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.globalretrying?view=azure-dotnet)
2. [OperationContext.Retrying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.retrying?view=azure-dotnet)

You could also try from Linq:

1. `.ToList()`
2. `.Where(x=>x.Conditions).ToList()` filter useless data in server side.
3. `.Take(10)` to page your result, because no one need all results in 1 page.